# Scanner and substring

Tags: java, substring

I'm trying to make a simple program that reads text files and gets specific data out of it. In the code below i try to get a position where i have quote. So let's say file.txt contents are:

```
aaaaaaa"bbbbb"ccccc
ddd"ee"ffff
g"hhhhhh"iii"gggg"
```

So i should have an array list with all positions of quotes (al = [7, 13, 3, 6, 1, 8, 12, 17]).
The problem is that i can't seem to get a substring out of each line which im reading from text. I want to get the text that's inside quotes. Output should be something like this:

```
bbbbb
ee
hhhhhh
gggg
```

Code:

```
File temp = new File("file.txt");
Scanner file = new Scanner(temp);
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (file.hasNext()) {
    String k = file.next();
    //System.out.println(k);
    int position = 0;
    while (position >= 0) {
        position = k.indexOf('"', position + 1);
        //System.out.println(position);   
        al.add(position);
    }
    System.out.println(k.substring(position,position+1));
}
```

Comment: And what's what are you getting with your program?, what's the problem?

Comment: If you want the strings inside the quotes you should use regex

Comment: Regex with `Pattern` and `Matcher` should be useful in case you have more than 2 quote sets in your strings. Any reason you don't use regex here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine using Regex as suggested above, then you can just do this (assuming the quotes open and close in the same line):

```
    List<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("files/input.txt")).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
    for(String line : lines){
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line); 
        while(m.find())
            System.out.println(m.group(1).replaceAll("\"", ""));
    }
```

I hope it helps.